# jQuery json/jsonp does not fetch items on php server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, getjson

I have a web service written in php but I could not fetch data with jquery `getJSON()`.
It's my web service and works fine.

```
    <?php
include 'config.php';

$sql = "select s.id, s.title, s.content, s.date, s.confirm " . 
        "from sap s";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $sapList = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
    $data = array('items'=>$sapList);
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    //echo '{"items":'. json_encode($sapList,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'}'; 

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}


?>
```

I am trying to develop a jQuery mobile app.and source codes:event.js I used for loop in ***event.js***.because I want to pull data from multiple separate services.

```
var db=openDatabase('servicesDB','1.0','servcesdatabase', 2*1024*1024);
tablo();
var olaylar;

$('#eventListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    console.log("geteventlist fonksiyon running");
    getEventList();
});

function getEventList() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM services',[],function (tx,sonuc) {
            var toplam=sonuc.rows.length;

            var kayit="";
            var id="";
            var ad="";
            var url="";
            $('#olaylar li').remove();  
            for (var i=0;i < toplam; i++) {
                kayit=sonuc.rows.item(i);
                id=kayit.id;
                ad=kayit.ad;
                url=kayit.url;

                $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data) {
                    olaylar = data.items;
                    $.each(olaylar, function(index, olay) {
                        /*var confirm="";
                        switch(olay.confirm){
                        case 0:
                            confirm="accept";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            confirm="wait";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            confirm="reject";
                            break;
                        }*/
                        $('#olaylar').append(
                            '<li><a href="eventDetails.html?id=' + olay.id + '">' +
                            '<img src="pics/mr.jpg"/>' +
                            '<h4>' + olay.title + '</h4>' +
                            '<p>' + olay.confirm + '</p>' +
                            '</a></li>');
                    });

                    $('#olaylar').listview('refresh');
                    alert("getjsondan cikti");
                });
            }   
        }, hata);
    });
}

function tablo(){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS services('
                +'id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
                +'ad VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, url VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)');

    });
}

function hata(transaction, err){
    alert("Hata oldu : "+err.message);
    return false;
}
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Personel Listesi</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="eventListPage" data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Event List</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="olaylar" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/events.js"></script>
    <script src="js/eventDetails.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried `$.getJSON(...){ alert("in getjson");` but that does not work. this `alert.getjson` function does not work. But it works very well before, now the `getjson` function returns blank as if no data has been retrieved.. I need your help,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am little doubt about `'{"items":'. json_encode($sapList,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'}'`. I am  not sure whether the above piece of code frame proper json.

The better way is create your JSON structure in PHP associate array itself and then generate the JSON in single stroke like as follows,

```
<?php

// Some code
$data = array('item'=>$sapList);
echo json_encode($sapList);

?>
```

Note: Since I haven't tested my code and it is GET request, you can test your code by directly type the URL in browsers address-bar. And copy and paste printed code in chrome's console and validate them in Javascript.

*OR*

Use online JSON validator like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks for reply.but i always use this template of web service in php.and never had any conflict.I'll try anyway.Do you have some doubts in JavaScript?

Comment: there is an error in chrome's console."Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : getsaplist.php:1 " getsaplist.php have above.I did as you said

Comment: i tried jsonlint.com and my json is valid.have not a problem.but doesnot work on my jquery...